# What do I do for property declarations of primitive types in iOS5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

We're building an app that only targets iOS 5. When declaring properties of primitive types are these the correct modifiers?

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat lat;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat lng;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int othersHere;
```

Or should we just be using nonatomic?

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat lat;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat lng;
@property (nonatomic) int othersHere;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`assign` is the default type if omitted, so the 2 statements are the same, the first is just more explicit and easier to read.