# readwrite or assign, what do I use as a property modifier for a CGFloat

Tags: ios

I have been on an SO rampage, reading up about the various property modifiers. I know that assign acts similarly to unsafe_unretained, but what would i use for a standard readwrite property for a CGFloat? readwrite (the default) seems obvious but when would i use assign?

Comment: They modify different aspects of the property. `readwrite` and `readonly` specify wheter you can set or only get a property. `assign` vs. `retain` control if the property owns a strong reference to the value assigned to it. A. k. a. "what's the difference between Steve Jobs and a iambic pentameter?"

Comment: does readwrite implicitly set the ownership? ex @property(nonatomic)CGFloat someFloat;

Comment: No, it doesn't, but since `CGFloat` is not an Objective-C class, it cannot possibly be a `retain`, `strong` or `copy` property. It can only be `assign`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of properties in Objective C 2.0 for Primitive types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424962/use-of-properties-in-objective-c-2-0-for-primitive-types), [What do I do for @property declarations of primitive types in iOS 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9201634)

Comment: it is not a dup of that question. The question you link to talks just about using assign for properties. I am not asking which to use for primitive properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readwrite` and `assign` are not mutually exclusive, they serve different purposes. You can likely just declare it without specifying either and let it default to both `readwrite` and `assign`, which is almost certainly what you want.

Comment: The default when compiling with ARC is `strong`, not `assign`.

Comment: but a primitive cant use strong so wouldnt that default to assign?

Comment: Has to. It can't be anything but assign as a primitive. But, could also just declare `assign` explicitly for consistency sake if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You should use assign to non-object properties - any C types like int, float, double, enum, struct.

Answer (score 0):

`readwrite` and `readonly` are just about what getter and setter methods are created automatically. `assign` is to do with the memory management. If you set a property to `assign`, the automatically generated setter looks something like this:

```
@property (assign) int number;

- (void)setNumber:(int)newNumber
{
    number = newNumber;
}
```

I'm not sure how it is with ARC, but setting an object pointer (e.g. `NSString`) with assign caused a memory leak (the original value of the ivar wasn't released before its pointer was set to the new value).

AFAIK `assign` is the default for all properties, overridden by using strong etc.

Comment: im pretty sure strong is the default for all obj-c objects, and assign for primates.

Comment: @jfisk That would make more sense than assign. Just checked the docs and you're right: "Object properties are strong by default" http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: `strong` is the default when compiling with ARC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802511/what-are-the-defaults-values-for-property-in-ios

Comment: @JoshCaswell So I see, thanks. I probably should have read the ARC transition docs by now.

Comment: Well, in your defense, reading those docs seems to be a choice between [pedantic](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) and [glossy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), so it's understandable.